# vue and sockert error- the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vuejs2

I am trying to crate a chat app with vue and socket io.

[this error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LRZC.png)

[This is my node server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqI5R.png)

[this is my vue app code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuxAw.png)

node server is a individual app and vue is a individual app.How can I solve this problem. I am completely stuck with this problem.How can I solve this problem. when I trying to add this code on my vue app for connect with socket then I am getting this error.

> " import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
>
> import io from 'socket.io-client';
>
> Vue.use(VueSocketio, io('http://localhost:8890'));  "

Comment: Please post the code in text and Maybe use the default cors option. like `app.use(cors())` without the corsOption

Answer (score 0):

What I got to know from the error is you are accessing the socket server from your Vue app which runs at `127.0.0.1:8000`.

So, You for your server `127.0.0.1:8000` is the origin. Not `127.0.0.1:8890` which is the server's port itself.

Maybe, use the default cors option.

```
app.use(cors())
```

or in the `corsOption` set `origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"`

Hope this helps